# Selenium Web Driver Eclipse: Passing the username and password from json file or xml file

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, parameters

I need to test a login page with multiple username and password and need to pass the username and password from JSON file or XML file. is there a way to achieve it?

driver.findElement(By.id("usernameS")).sendKeys(username);
driver.findElement(By.id("passwordS")).sendKeys(password);

How should i reference the values in the sendkeys function in selenium web driver

Answer (score 0):

The below answer is based on assumption that the JSON is of below format:

```
{
    "testData": [{
        "userName": "test1",
        "password": "password1"
    }, {
        "userName": "test2",
        "password": "password2"
    }]
}
```

I would suggest using Jackson to deserialize the data. You will need jackson-core, jackson-annotations, jackson-databind jars of same versions in your classpath.

Create Class User as below:

```
public class User {
    private String userName;
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    private String password;
}
```

Create Class TestData as below:

```
public class TestData {
    List<User> testData;

    public List<User> getTestData() {
        return testData;
    }

    public void setTestData(List<User> testData) {
        this.testData = testData;
    }
}
```

Deserializing will be done as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        // You can read the json from property file/service call and store to string.
        String jsonString = "{\"testData\": [{\"userName\": \"test1\",\"password\": \"pwd1\"}, {\"userName\": \"test2\", \"password\": \"pwd2\" }]}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TestData obj = mapper.readValue(jsonString,TestData.class);
        for (User data : obj.getTestData()) {
             driver.findElement(By.id("usernameS")).sendKeys(data.getUserName());
             driver.findElement(By.id("passwordS")).sendKeys(data.getPassword());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf). Where you can use properties in xml file and use in code. For example:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("usernameS")).sendKeys(getBundle().getString("default.username"));
driver.findElement(By.id("passwordS")).sendKeys(getBundle().getString("default.password"));
```

Properties in xml file may look like below:

```
<testdata>
   <default>
      <username>user1</username>
      <password>user1pwd</password>
      <!-- other default properties-->
   </default>
   <admin>
      <username>adminUser</username>
      <password>adminpwd</password>
   </admin>
</testdata>
```

Furthermore for secure values you can have encrypted values in the properties file. for example:

```
<testdata>
   <default>
      <username>user1</username>
   </default>
   <encrypted>
      <default>
         <password>encrypted value</password>
   </default>
   </encrypted>
</testdata>
```

In above case, for password, you have provided `encrypted.default.password` in property. So when you use `default.password` you will get decrypted value.

In case of data driven test where you want to run your test with different data set you can use [inbuilt data-providers](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html) that feeds data form XML/JSON/CSV/EXCEL/DB.

There are many more features for web, mobile and web-services test automation. For web and mobile, you can take benefit of features like:

- [Locator repository](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/locator_repository.html)
- [Custom Component](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/custom_component.html)
- [Driver and Element Listeners](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html)
- [Resource management](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/managing_resources_for_different_env.html)
- Thread safe driver management

and many more.